# ReportViewer google Chrome date/time parameter shows hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: asp.net, datetime, reporting-services, reportviewer, datetimepicker

I have a ReportViewer in my website and several reports with date/time parameters. I actually need only date. In all browsers viewer shows only date in those fields, but in chrome it also shows time `00:00:00` which should be hidden. In Explorer i use default datepicker and in other browsers i use jquery ui datepicker. The problem exists only in Google Chrome.
Anybody has any solution?

EDIT:
This is javascript code for creating jquery ui calendar instead of default one (because in chrome default one is not showing up).

```
function addDatePicker() {
    $('#ctl00_Contentplaceholder_Viewer_ReportViewer div:has(input[type="text"]):not(:has(input[type="image"])):not(:has(input[type="checkbox"])):not(:has(img))')
    .each(function() {
        $(this).children('input[type="text"]').datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "~/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.30319.1&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd',
            OnSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var day = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate();
                var month = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;
                var year = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, day));
            },
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                if ((datestr = $(this).val().substring(0, 10)).length > 0) {
                    actDate = datestr.split('.');
                    year = actDate[0];
                    month = actDate[1] - 1;
                    day = actDate[2];
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, day));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, day));
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

As tried to fix my problem, i realised that it is not in javascript, but in report viewer or chrome/safari itself. In webkit browsers reportviewer shows date together with time. Anybody has an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Did you format your date in ReportViewer ? FormatDateTime(Fields!DeliveryDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)

Comment: Is it possible to set format for user specified parameter? Where should i put your expression? I need specific date format in the field where user enters date.

Comment: Yes, you can click on the Textbox in the report designer and create an Expression.

Comment: There is no textbox for parameters in my report. All textboxes are generated automatically by SSRS.

Comment: How do you get the jQuery UI DatePicker to tap into the input fields generated by the ReportViewer? Can you show some code?

Comment: I just added that code. My first thought was that i have bug in this code, but it should work not correctly in all browsers then.

Comment: It should give you the same problem in firefox too, do you not see the time part in firefox?

Comment: Damn... I have tis problem only in Chrome and Safari. And now i know that the problem is with javascript. Because i use jquery ui calendar only in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Ok, i am starting to tear my hear off... i changed `OnClose` to `OnSelect` back and it works now. But fixing original dates is a problem, because when `fixDates` function runs, it changes text in fields, to ReportViewer postbacks and i can't see report (it's just empty).